# When can you visualise a graph as a scatterplot?

Tags: graph-theory

If you have a graph G=(V,E) it seems the edges are a relation on the cartesian product $$E\subseteq V\times V$$ 
so if a bijection from the vertices to the axes of a scatterplot is possible then the graph's edges can be represented by a point in the scatterplot, maybe colorised if it is a weighted graph with values in a subset of the natural numbers. When does this work? I don't understand enough of ordinals and such to know when the bijection is possible. Thank you!

Comment: This is called an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and it works for all simple graphs (between any pair of vertices you have at most one edge), directed or no.

Comment: Right! How silly of me to forget about it. Thank you for reminding me! Is there anything in graph theory that is like analysis of functions but on graphs ? With derivatives and such?

Comment: Apropos your comment: [Functions, graphs, and adjacency matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36098/856)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Are functional and left total edges  uninteresting? If the vertices are tuples which are mapped to equivalence classes of tuples then Rm->Rn should have a adjecency matrix is my thinking though, I don't understand all in it.

Comment: @dtldarek Would you mind converting your comment into an answer?

Comment: @AndrewSalmon Done.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, converted from comment.

This is called an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and it works for all simple graphs (between any pair of vertices you have at most one edge), directed or no.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$